# Remove Controls from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have some small maps on my page that i show markers with marker clusters.

I really don't want any zoom or other tools displayed on this map. Partly because the tools don't even display correctly (no matter the size of the canvas).

I am using `gmaps4rails` Gem

here is a picture of what i have now:

[image]

I want to remove what i have blocked in red:

[image]

Here is my coding:

```
<div style='padding: 6px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
'>
  <div id="map2" style='width: 450px; height: 200px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    handler2 = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { clusterer: {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 5} } });
    handler2.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map2'}}, function(){
        handler2.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash2.to_json %>);
        handler2.getMap().setZoom(3);
        handler2.map.centerOn([39.828127,-98.579404]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+controls+from+google+maps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [google maps doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions), you can do it with `disableDefaultUI`.

So pass it in provider object:

```
provider: {disableDefaultUI: true }
```

[See plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nPGUWR1aK32cZQWfRhdn?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you tremediously... i had saw the disableDefaultUI: true but was not sure how to implement it into the coding i had... i kept seeing it in mapOptions = {} I guess that mapOptions can go in the provider: {} section.